# logic to print a number series 1,n,2,n-1,3,n-2,... series should be 1 to n(the input given)

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying my hands on basic programming and I came across this question. I have a function with a return type as string, that takes an integer input and has to print the series mentioned. Here's what I did.

```
String s=new String("h");
int[] a=new int[n];
int k=1;
for(int i=0;i<n;i+=2)
{
  a[i]=b;//line6
  a[i+1]=n-(b-1);//line7
  b++;
} 
s=Arrays.toString(a);
return s;
```

When I enter an "even" no. like 4. I get the proper result [1,4,2,3].

But when I enter "odd" no. like 5. I get an ArrayOutOfBoundException

I Know where Im going wrong at line6 and line7 but I'm not getting an idea how to modify it accordingly.

I also wish to return the string as 1 n 2 n-1 3 n-2 ... instead of [1,n,2,n-1,3,n-2,..]

Comment: what is the variable `b`?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have a loop running from `i = 0` to `i < n`, and you are trying to access `a[i + 1]`. This runs fine on even numbers because you're incrementing `2` each time, and the last iteration checks for `a[n - 2]` and `a[n - 1]`.

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` occurs on odd numbers, however, because the last iteration attempts to access `a[n - 1]` and `a[n]`.

One way to modify the loop would be to increment only by `1`, and set the value of `a[i]` by checking the parity of `i` inside the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++, b++) {
    a[i] = (i % 2 == 0)? b: (n - (b - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

consider the next approach:

```
for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++)
{
   a[2*i] = i+1;
   a[2*i+1] = n-i;
} 
if (n&1==1)  //how to check for oddity in Java?
  a[n-1] = (n+1)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

The inside of your loop should look like

```
a[i] = b;
if (i + 1 < n) { // check the bounds before writing at i+1
    a[i + 1] = n - (b - 1);
}
b++;
```

The reason for that is that when having odd numbers (e.g. 5) `i` gets to become 4 in the last iteration of the loop, 4 is smaller than 5, therefore the code enters the loop, then you access `a` at index `4`, which is okay, but then you try to access it at `4+1`, which is `5`, but the array does not have an index 5 because.

Answer (score 0):

Split the problem up into two smaller problems:

### Generating all values for even indices

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i += 2)
    a[i] = i + 1;
```

### Generating all values for odd incides

```
for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i += 2)
    a[i] = n - i / 2;
```

Thanks to integer-division `i / 2` of an odd number can substitute `(i - 1) / 2`.

### Full code

```
int[] a = new int[n];

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i += 2)
    a[i] = i + 1;

for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i += 2)
    a[i] = n - i / 2;

return Arrays.toString(a);
```